# What is different between these options how to set class to other one in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Please can someone explain me what is the different between these options how to set necessary class to other one. In our project we use all of this in different classes and I am confused why.

in class extended DispatcherServlet:

we use:

```
@Override
protected void initFrameworkServlet() throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getWebApplicationContext();
    myClass = context.getBean("myClass", MyClass.class);
}
```

in Class extended SoapMessageDispatcher:

we use:

```
private MyClass myClass;


@Required
public void setMyClass(MyClass myClass) {
    this.myClass = myClass;
}
```

in class implements ApplicationContextAware

we use

```
MyClass myClass = applicationContext.getBean(MyClass.class);
```

and the most expanded is just:

```
@Inject
private MyClass myClass;
```

why I can't use just last option in all cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring knows various types of dependency injections.

Explicit injection done via xml file:

```
<bean id="monitoringManager" class="some.Class">
    <property name="someProperty" value="value" />
</bean>
```

In that case value if injected into bean instance via setter in your example.

Autowiring (`@Inject` in your example) Spring's CDI alternative (check [Java EE 6 Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnr.html)). Difference between first example is, that Spring looks into context for the bean of specified type (unless you use i.e. `@Named` annotation) but in xml definition is an explicit instance injected into the bean.

Last example (`applicationContext.getBean(...)`) gets instance of bean from application context just in runtime on the specific row in your code but the other approaches above injects instances of beans during initialization.

All approaches you mentioned leads to same target-having injected instance of specific bean. The first two examples injects required dependency reference to the bean initialization. The last one just gets reference to the bean instance into local variable instead of spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the last option on all spring managed beans. For object instances that are not managed by the Spring context (those which you create by invoking the constructor manually), you need an applicationContext to reach beans in the Spring context, and this corresponds to your second usage.

Answer (score 0):

@Inject is same as @Autowired. you can use these two options to access instaces of all spring managed beans.

check MyClass is a a spring managed bean of not ..It should have @Service

Answer (score 0):

The `DispatcherServlet` is a `HttpServlet`, defined in the web.xml and therefore instantiated by the servlet container. Thus it is no spring managed bean and not autowired. This is the reason why you can't use `@Inject` or `@Autowired` out of the box.

Nevertheless you can create an own servlet class that extends the `DispatcherServlet` and add autowire, e.g.

```
public abstract class AutowireCapableDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    @Override
    protected void initFrameworkServlet() {             
         super.initFrameworkServlet();
         AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory = wac
                     .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
         autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(this);

         WebApplicationContext wac = getWebApplicationContext();
         ApplicationContext parent = wac.getParent();
         if(parent != null){
             autowireCapableBeanFactory = parent.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
             autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(this);
         }    
    }
}
```

You should then be able to do something like this:

```
public class MyServlet extends AutowireCapableDispatcherServlet {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;
}
```